# wget multiple files with numeric patterns

Tags: linux, wget

I'd like to `wget` several files, with an incrementing `YEAR` param.

the list of files would be something like this:

```
http://example.com/2000/Q1/file.txt
http://example.com/2001/Q1/file.txt
http://example.com/2002/Q1/file.txt
http://example.com/2003/Q1/file.txt
```

And I would like to also increment an `-O` output file name option too.

```
wget -O file.{2000..2003}.Q1.txt http://example.com/{2000..2003}/Q1/file.txt
```

So that way I'd end up with this:

```
file.2000.Q1.txt
file.2001.Q1.txt
file.2002.Q1.txt
file.2003.Q1.txt
```

I tried a couple variants of that, and I get minor errors and the output file names seem to not increment. How can I get the desired file output names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the same value at multiple places, you need to have the value in a variable, in a loop, for example:

```
for year in {2000..2003}; do
     echo wget http://example.com/$year/Q1/file.txt -O file.$year.Q1.txt
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple `wget` commands:

```
for y in $(seq 2000 2003); do
     wget http://example.com/$y/Q1/file.txt -O file.$y.Q1.txt
done
```